# Is it possible to put swf inside another swf to change the keyboard functions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I have a swf file runs some kind of emulator using a library made with adobe alchemy. this swf run games and we can control them using keyboard and i don't have an option to remap the buttons in the keyboard, so I'm asking is it possible to put this swf inside another swf containing an interface to remap the buttons on the keyboard? if it's possible is that gonna affect the performance of the emulator.
can you give me an example how to do such stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could come up with was something like this, which captures a standard `KeyboardEvent`, then dispatches a new `KeyboardEvent` with a remapped `keyCode` value.

The only issue at the moment is that each press will dispatch two `KeyboardEvents`. The first will be the original and the latter will be the remapped version.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyHandler);

function keyHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(!e.cancelable)
    {
        var map:Object = {
            65: 20,
            66: 13
        };

        // Set up you own event.
        // The new KeyboardEvent is cancelable, so we can track it as such.
        var kbd:KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent(e.type, true, true);
        kbd.keyCode = e.keyCode;

        for(var i:String in map)
        {
            // Set the keyCode of the new KeyboardEvent to the mapped value
            // as defined above.
            if(e.keyCode === int(i)) kbd.keyCode = map[i];
        }

        stage.dispatchEvent(kbd);
    }


    // Notice that you will be notified twice of a KeyboardEvent; once for
    // the original and once for the new one with the remapped (if applicable)
    // keyCode value.
    trace(e.keyCode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond, but you didn't answer my question is it possible or not?

Comment: @Dora Well, yes, it's mostly possible using the code in my answer. You can't remap the default KeyboardEvents that are dispatched, but you can do what I have done and dispatch new ones. If the games used some type of library for the user input management that could utilise a new KeyboardEvent model for the keyCode data, then you could easily do it. Unfortunately I doubt that's the case.